# Why another Jquery plugin is not worked in Jquery append?

Tags: jquery

[This is the code](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Z4yYf/3/)

First time its work fine for me.That is it open the modal box.But the second time It wont open the Modal box when I add the anchor tag using Jquery append.Why?What I need to change its going to be work?Thanks.

Update:

I am using [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

```
<input type="text" name="maxprocedure"  id="maxprocedure" value="1"/>
<div id="procedurecontainer">
  <a title="Google Site" class="thickbox" href="http://www.google.com?width=200&height=200" >Open Here</a>
</div>
<input type="button" id="addprocedure" value="add"/>`
```

Jquery Code is

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#addprocedure').click(function()
    {
      //alert($("#maxprocedure").val());
      var maxvalue=$("#maxprocedure").val();
      for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
      {
        var idvalue=parseInt(maxvalue)+i;
        $("#procedurecontainer").append('<input type="text" value="" id="procedurecode'+idvalue+'" name="procedurecode'+idvalue+'"></input><a title="Google Site" class="thickbox" href="http://google.com?width=200&height=200">Open Here</a>');
        $("#maxprocedure").val(idvalue);

      }
  });

});
```

Comment: please try to post  code here [SO] . what if the link is dead....

Comment: I can't seem to load jsfiddle right now, but as a stab in the dark, are you appending the link after you bind the click handler? If so, the new links won't have their click handlers bound.  If you're dynamically adding a lot of elements, you should consider using delegate or live for binding your handlers - those will work with new elements.

Comment: @jmar777  I changed the click event to live then its working fine.Thanks.

Comment: The thickbox plugin is no longer maintained. It's probably not a good idea to use it in a new project unless you absolutely must.

Answer (score 1):

Thickbox attaches to all `a`, `area` and `input` elements containing the `thickbox` class when the document finishes to load.

If you add more elements of the same type after the document has loaded, the popup window won't show up when you click them.

A fix without changing the plugin implementation would be to manually bind the new elements to thickbox.

Fixed code:

```
var idvalue=parseInt(maxvalue)+i,
    //store the element in a variable for better reading
    $hyperlink = $('<a title="Google Site" class="thickbox" href="http://google.com?width=200&height=200">Open Here</a>');

//this attaches the element to the thickbox plugin
tb_init($hyperlink);

$("#procedurecontainer")
    .append('<input type="text" value="" id="procedurecode'+idvalue+'" name="procedurecode'+idvalue+'"></input>')
    .append($hyperlink);

$("#maxprocedure").val(idvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the "thickbox" initialization only happens when the main page is first loaded. When you add those new links, the thickbox plugin has no idea that they're there, and so they're not initialized like your first link.

You need to call "tb_init" with a selector for your newly-added elements after you append them.

Answer (score 0):

u have to call tb_init('a.thickbox') after appending the a tags  chk it out : http://www.jsfiddle.net/Z4yYf/7/

Comment: yes i just saw the TB_window gets added twice after the first click no clue why but i guess u should choose a different modal like jquery-ui modal http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal or http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/external.html